# Creating an Archive using a Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, customization, archives

I recently adjusted the twentyten theme to display archives in a three column grid.  In doing so, it seems that the archive has lost the ability to display posts from the specified taxonomy.

For instance, a taxonomy type is 'Flowers', with a specific flower being 'Rose'.  When the 'Rose' archive is displayed, it simply lists all posts.  I believe I have narrowed the problem to this line:

`query_posts('cat=0&posts_per_page=12&paged='.$paged);`

I understand that it is just listing all 'uncategorized' posts, but I am at a loss with how to have display a specific taxonomy archive as would normally be done for a category archive.

Any ideas?  I am guessing it isn't as hard as I am making it, but I have searched for hours with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try just removing the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add the current term to you query so if its category, tag or custom taxonomy you will get the posts with the current term, try changing this:

```
query_posts('cat=0&posts_per_page=12&paged='.$paged);
```

with this:

```
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
query_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => $paged, $taxonomyName => $term_slug));
```

Answer (score -1):

+1 to Milo answer. But if you need to change the post_per_page parameter, try this:

```
global $query_string;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts($query_string.'&paged='.$paged.'&posts_per_page=12');
```

Comment: I understood that you needed archive for a custom post type, not a taxonomy. Sorry!